# Session not working when using uploadify with firefox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, uploadify

My uploadify script is working in all browsers including IE. But not working in firefox. I have three files.
1>Contains the uploadify script and variables
2>Is the newuploadify.php which starts the sessions and gives the session variables some values.
3>Is to insert data in database based on the sessions.

This works beautifully in all the browsers except chromium (not Chrome) and Firefox.

Somehow the session is not being passed from the second file to the third file in Firefox.

My scripts

1>
`

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
<style type="text/css">
    .uploadify-button {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .uploadify:hover .uploadify-button {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploadify/uploadify.css" />
<script>
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j("#photocancelbtn").hide();
  $j("#photouploadstartbtn").hide();
   $j("#filein").hide();
  $j("#filein").fadeIn(8000);
$j(function() {
    $j('#file_upload').uploadify({
        auto : false,
            'swf'      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'newuploadify.php',
             // Put your options here

        'queueSizeLimit' : 1,
        'checkExisting' : '/uploadify/check-exists.php',
        'multi'    : false,
        'buttonText' : 'Add Photo',
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.JPG',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '5MB',
        'onClearQueue' : function(queueItemCount) {
               $j("#photocancelbtn").hide();
               $j("#photouploadstartbtn").hide();
        },
        'onSelect' : function(file) {
              $j("#photocancelbtn").show();
              $j("#photouploadstartbtn").show();
        },

        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                $j("#photocancelbtn").hide();
               $j("#photouploadstartbtn").hide();

               changeBtnText();
    }


    }); /* closing uploadify line*/

}); /* closing funciton line*/
}); /*closing document ready function*/
function changeBtnText() {
    $j('#file_upload').uploadify('settings','buttonText','Change Photo');
}
function restoreBtnText() {
    $j('#file_upload').uploadify('settings','buttonText','Add Photo');
}   

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="filein">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</td>
<td id="btns">
<a id="photouploadstartbtn" href="javascript:$j('#file_upload').uploadify('upload')">Start Upload</a><br>
<a id="photocancelbtn" href="javascript:$j('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel','*');">Remove photo</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Also tried passing data through scriptData in above code but still the result is same.

2>

`

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
require('connection.php');
$targetFolder = '/images/'; // Relative to the root
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $randomid=uniqid();
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/'.$randomid.$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','JPG','PNG'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    $fp     = fopen($tempFile, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tempFile));
    $data = addslashes($data);
    fclose($fp);



move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
$_SESSION['photopath'] = $randomid.$_FILES['Filedata']['name']; //Just storing the file name for the path.
$_SESSION['photocheck']='Y';
/*The above sessions are setting but are not being passed to the third file.
error_log($_SESSION['photopath']);
error_log($_SESSION['photocheck']);
error_log(session_id());

    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';

    }
}
?>
```

`

3>

`

```
#Getting if photo is added.
                if(isset($_SESSION['photocheck'])){
                    $photocheck=$_SESSION['photocheck'];
                    error_log('Photocheck=');
                    error_log($photocheck);
                    unset($_SESSION['photocheck']);
                }
                if(isset($_SESSION['photopath'])){
                //$photo=$_SESSION['photo'];#Encoding string as image. For using mysqli no need to do this step.just bind param as string.
                $photopath=$_SESSION['photopath'];
                error_log('Photopath=');
                    error_log($photopath);
                unset($_SESSION['photopath']);
                }

                #Inserting 
                if($photocheck=='Y'){
                error_log('Entered into insert q');

                }
                else{
                error_log('Did not enter !!');
                }
```

`

I am getting Did not enter when doing with firefox and Entered into insert q when using other browsers. Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
         session_start();
      }
?>
```

PHP knows not to start another session so you can let as it is

```
<?php
     session_start();
?>
```

Also make sure you don't have any output in `require('connection.php');` if it's only `PHP` script you can omit the last `?>` of php block, just to make sure you don't have any extra space.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(@$_REQUEST['SESSION_ID'] && ($session_id=$_REQUEST['SESSION_ID']) !=session_id()){
    session_destroy();
    session_id($session_id);
    @session_start();    
}
```

The right answer